# error as Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'

Tags: django

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    interests = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    twitter_profile = models.URLField(blank=True)
    instagram_profile = models.URLField(blank=True)
    linkedin_profile = models.URLField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_profile'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class UserRelationship(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='following')
    followed_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_followers'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} follows {self.followed_user.username}"
```

error:

```
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'accounts.CustomUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
```

basically i want create user profile by inherit abstractuser class in django models.py for my social chat app,
but i m not able to migrate this models with above error.

Comment: Remove `django.contrib.auth` from the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

You should *remove* `django.contrib.auth.models` from the `INSTALLED_APPS`, so:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    # 'django.contrib.auth',  #  🖘 remove
    # …
]
```

otherwise there are two user models active: `User` and `CustomUser`, with both the same `related_name` from a model like `Group`.

The fact that you import from the `AbstractUser` from `django.contrib.auth.models` is not important.

Comment: Willem, I don't think removing `django.contrib.auth` will solve that problem. I think, the error will gone when he removes `CustomUser` from these two field, and add `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe: no, that is a different problem. The problem is, as the error message describes, that there is an overlap of two `related_fields`, especially targeting the `Group` model, these originate from the `PermissionMixin` (which is inherited by `AbstractUser`): as you can see here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L264 it has a `related_name='user_set', but since there are thus two, that both point to `Group` that is an ambiguity, that is exactly what the error message says, that two fields targeting `Group` with the same `related_name`.

Comment: But Removing or commenting out `django.contrib.auth` in `INSTALLED_APPS` will prevent Django from using the built-in authentication system, including the `AbstractUser` model.

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe: no not at all, Django's auth module is still a Python module so you can import it, what will not happen is that Django loads it as a module, which makes not much sense of course. The authentication for example works with `get_user_model()` so that will (lazily) load the user model picked by the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` string. It is a common misconception that you need to ship something as an app to let it work.